# More elegant way to get nested object properties by name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I have this *working* code, which retrieves the names of object properties from a JS object which (unfortunately!) is out of my scope. So I cannot change how this object is built. But I want to (and do) extract the names of the properties, that are marked as `true`, as an array, to be able to handle this object easier.

Object:

```
{
    group1: {
        foo: true,
        itemFoo: "Name of foo", // This is what I want, because foo is true
        bar: false,
        itemBar: "Name of bar", // I dont want this, bar is false
        // ...
    },
    group2: {
        baz: true,
        itemBaz: "Name of baz", // I want this too
        // ...
    },
    uselessProp1: "not an object",
    // ...
}
```

Working Code:

```
var items = [];

for (var m in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[m] == 'object') {
        for (var n in obj[m]) {
            if (obj[m][n] === true) {
                items.push(obj[m]['item' + (n.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + n.slice(1))]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: does someone know a more elegant way of achieving this traversal with underscore.js or plain node.js or any other library? I did experiments with `_.filter`, but did not come up with a solution.

Comment: This is the best way because is readable, therefore maintainable, easy to change, find bugs, not depends on third-party modules, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var result = [];
_.chain(obj).filter(_.isObject).each(function(t) {
    _(t).each(function(val, key) {
        if(val === true)
            result.push(t['item' + key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.substr(1)])
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I've come so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/kradmiy/28NZP/

```
var process = function (obj) {
var items = [];

var objectProperties = _(obj).each(function (rootProperty) {
    // exit from function in case if property is not an object
    if (!_(rootProperty).isObject()) return;

    _(rootProperty).each(function (value, key) {
        // proceed only if property is exactly true
        if (value !== true) return;
        var searchedKey = 'item' + (key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.slice(1));
        // check that parent has this property...
        if (rootProperty.hasOwnProperty(searchedKey)) {
            // ...and push that to array
            items.push(rootProperty[searchedKey]);
        }
    });
});

  return items;
};
```

Comment: The best way to make it readable is not to improve the algorythm itself, but rather split code into several function calls. So iteration will be performed like that: `_(obj).each(objectProperty(filterTrueValues));`. But right now, I'm not able to play further with that :)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out something :

```
Micha’s Golden Rule
Micha Gorelick, a data scientist in NYC, coined the following rule:
Do not store data in the keys of a JSON blob.
```

Your JSON should use :

```
{//group1
  groupname:"group1",
  items :[
    {//item1
       itemcheck:true,
       itemname:'itemBar'
    },
    ...
  ]
},
...
```

If you store itemname in key. You will have problem when traversing the JSON, because your 'itemFoo' would be using 'foo'(indirectly) to get its value. Your data structure, is the problem here. Searching your JSON is tricky. Once you follow the rule, your code will be elegant automatically.

Comment: Yes i know, but as I pointed out in my question, the JSON is served by a source out of my control. I would have built this JSON different too, but all I am left with is converting this into something more reasonable :)